# Play Framework with Eclipse enable suggestions and remove errors

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator

I've recently started learning Play framework and I've been playing around with some of the templates.

I've created an eclipse project using "activator eclipse" and imported it into my IDE but what I'm wondering is there a way within eclipse to enable suggestions on Play framework libraries/syntax so that when I type something and press CTRL + Space I get a suggestion/auto fill.

Also the app runs fine but looks like there is errors in my java class:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the latest version of sbt-eclipse (in your `project/plugins.sbt`), which is `5.1.0`:
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/releases

`5.1.0` did fix the problem with the `index` not being found.

Now remove the project from eclipse, run `activator eclipse` again, and the re-add the project to eclipse.
Like described [in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE), make sure you have

```
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test)
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)
```

set in your `build.sbt`.

**Tip:** Also add

```
EclipseKeys.withSource := true
EclipseKeys.withJavadoc := true
```

to `build.sbt` so also the source of all the libraries are fetched (if available) and also the libraries javadocs are added.